# What are the day to day activities a sharepoint admin do on regular basis

Tags: administration

What are the day to day activities a sharepoint administrator does, please do provide a detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

On a high level, this person has all the technical knowledge when it comes to installing the SharePoint farm (including IIS, SQL, and Network), configuring its service applications and timer jobs, and high level management of permission such as assigning people with respective permissions. He/She ensures and monitors that the SharePoint farm is in healthy state.

On a non-technical level, this person is involved in liaising with stakeholders of sites and giving rights to respective individuals for ownership.

There are several useful links that discusses the detailed role, here are some of them:

1. [Top 10 Resposiblities of a SharePoint Admin](http://www.sharepoint-zone.com/2014/02/sharepoint-admin-what-do-they-really-do.html)
2. [Similar question in Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/477ae5c0-baed-42b7-b9a7-256181729f01/what-are-the-duties-of-sharepoint-administrator)
3. [SharePoint Admin as Jack of all trades](http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Article/128/What-is-a-SharePoint-Administrator.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's depend upon the company but typically sharepoint admin responsible atleast for this.

- Installation , configuration of sharepoint
- patching sharepoint farm (applying CU, Sp1)
- making sure sharepoint up n running
- sites collection up n accessible
- monitoring the logs and making sure nothing wrong
- making sure enough disk space on database server n server drives
- growth of site collections n databases
- monitor the timer jobs, health rules.
- customizations check.

[Overview of monitoring in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748636.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[What is a SharePoint Administrator?](http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Article/128/What-is-a-SharePoint-Administrator.aspx)

Comment: Can you please provide me steps to perform the above tasks

Comment: Installation and configuration not required

Comment: check this technet most of monitoring covered here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748636.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Assalawalaikum .. Can a subsite or database which is deleted can be restored using content database and how